# Arithmetic Cuda program compilation error

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, pointer-arithmetic

Am working on a CUDA program which am new to. I encountered the error below, tried fixing but came to a halt. Can anyone take a look and tell me what I might be missing? Any help will be appreciated.

```
Error   5   error : too few arguments in function call   
Error   6   error : argument of type "int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "size_t"    
Error   7   error : argument of type "unsigned int" is incompatible with parameter of type "cudaMemcpyKind" 
Error   8   error : too many arguments in function call 2010\Projects\lab\lab\kernel.cu 54  1   lab
Error   9   error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 500
#include <cuda.h>

__global__ void InitialAdd(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *z, int n, float aspa, float bspb, float apa, float bpb)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.x * threadIdx.x;
    aspa = (-*a);
    bspb = (-*b);
    aspa = (10,*a);
    bspb = (10,*b);
    *z = (a,2) + (b,2) + aspa + bspb + apa + bpb;
    if(i < n)
        c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}

int main(void)
{
    int *a, *b, *c, *z;
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c, *d_z;


    a = (int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    b = (int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    c = (int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    z = (int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc( &d_a, SIZE*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc( &d_b, SIZE*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc( &d_c, SIZE*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc( &d_z, SIZE*sizeof(int));

    for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        a[i] =i;
        b[i] =i;
        c[i] =0;
        z[i] =i;

    }

    cudaMemcpy( d_a, a, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( d_b, b, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( d_c, c, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( d_z, z, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );


    InitialAdd<<< 4 , SIZE >>>( d_a, d_b, d_c, d_z, SIZE);


    cudaMemcpy( c, d_z, d_c, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        printf("c[%d] = %d\n", i, c[i], *z);

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    free(z);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);
    cudaFree(d_z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exaclty is unclear in the errors? what more can we tell you than that you have wrong number and wrong types of parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I can see one clear problem in this line:

```
cudaMemcpy( c, d_z, d_c, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
```

You're passing 5 arguments, whereas `cudaMemcpy` only expects 4. I guess you're trying to copy from `d_z` to `c`, so it would be:

```
cudaMemcpy( c, d_z, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
```

i.e. remove the `d_c`.

Comment: thanks it worked, but on this line InitialAdd<<< 3 , SIZE >>>( d_a, d_b, d_c, d_z, SIZE); i got this; Error 5 error : too few arguments in function call

Comment: That's because you are not passing enough arguments! Your kernel `InitialAdd` expects 9.

Comment: i have implemented the suggestion made so but still have the Error below on this line
InitialAdd<<< 4, SIZE >>>( d_a, d_b, d_c, d_z, SIZE, d_aspa, d_bspb, d_apa, d_bpb);
 
7 error : argument of type "float *" is incompatible with parameter of type "float"

Comment: That error message tells you _exactly_ what the problem is. Those variables should be of type `float`, not `float*`.

Comment: __global__ void InitialAdd(int *a, int *b, int *z, int n, float *aspa, float *bspb, float *apa, float *bpb)
{
 int i = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.x * threadIdx.x;
 *aspa = (-*a);
 *bspb = (-*b);
 *aspa = (10,*a);
 *bspb = (10,*b);
 *z = (a,2) + (b,2) + aspa + bspb + apa + bpb;
 for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
 {
  *z= (a,2) + (b,2) + aspa + bspb + apa + bpb;

 }
}
The code seems to be working fine but still have this two errors